# Work out the adjoint of $T(x,y) = (y,-x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

this seems like a simple question but I don't understand it.

We define a transformation $T(x,y) = (y,-x)$. We want to work out what the adjoint is.

I know the answer: $T^*(x,y) = (-y,x)$ but how?

Is it because $T(x,y)$ is an operation on the first component $x$ and $T^*(x,y)$ is an operation on the second component $y$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjoint of $T$ is defined as the operator $T^*$ such that
$$
\langle T(x,y),(a,b)\rangle=\langle (x,y),T^*(a,b)\rangle
$$

Let $T^*(a,b)=(u,v)$, from the definition of $T$ you have:
$$
\langle (y,-x),(a,b)\rangle=\langle (x,y),(u,v)\rangle \iff ay-bx=ux+vy
$$
since this have to be true for all $(x,y)$ you find: $u=-b$ and $v=a$, so:
$T^*(a,b)=(-b,a)$.

Comment: Wow, I just worked it out on my own and this makes SO much sense. This is an incredible answer. I wish I could give you 100 of my reputation thank you so much.